# 'Sufferer of ' vs 'sufferer from'

Tags: expressions, prepositions

If one suffers from a disease, is one better considered a sufferer *from* a disease, or a sufferer *of* a disease?

Answer (score 2):

One both *suffers from* a disease, and is *a sufferer of* that disease.

Comment: Any source for this? Or is it based on ‘common sense’, that dreadful misnomer?